# Guidance of Offered Salary with Mandatory Expenses - Gothenburg

Tags: salary, payroll-taxes, sweden

I have 6.9 years of experience in IT industry and 6.6 years of experience in DEVOPS skills which includes automation of deployment, Jenkins, Artifactory, Ansible, Artifactory, Dockerization and Containerization, AWS Cloud experience, Shell Scripting, Powershell Scripting and Groovy Scripting also.

I worked on 3 companies in India and currently my CTC is 15,30,000 LPA and the cost of living is low when compared to Gothenburg, Sweden

Here is the story,

I got an interview call from xx company in Gothenburg, Sweden and this opportunity is for full-time position with work-permit visa. I have completed all the rounds with that company and the feedback is positive. So finally they offered me 6,25,000 SEK per Annum + 7% of Variable Pay + Relocation Expenses (15,000 SEK) as well

I don't have any friends (or) relatives to check whether the current salary is enough or not except watching some of the youtube videos and some of the surfing content from internet. So I have few queries to clarify with you all to confirm the offer whether it's good (or) bad decision to make in-order to have a better life in future and earning more salary than what I get currently. I have listed some of the concerns such as below,

1. I want to know the net salary from the offered pay because when I
   checked with final discussion they didn't disclose it to me.
   Eventhough I surfed most of the websites and it varies the amountAfter we calculated the net salary, Do you think that this xxx SEK
   will enough to live a normal life with my family of 2 (Myself and
   wife)

   What is the mandatory expenses after I receive take home for each
   month? I have listed it below so far I know and please add if I
   missed out any

Transportation
Mobile Bills
Food and Groceries
Renting Apartment
Internet Bills
Water and Electricity Bill (if any)
Maintenance of the apartment (if any)
Subscription charges (if any)

I'm not sure about the percentage of taxes based on the offered salary because when I surfed I can see that there is a municipality tax, national tax, etc...

After all the expenses calculation, Do you think that I need to tell them to raise my salary? If yes, Could you please tell how much? Because I don't know the job market based on my skill sets? If yes, How much salary that employer need to give?

Comment: Is this on-topic for PFF?

Comment: Since we do not know your spending habits and what is "normal" for you so we cannot answer if it will be enough. Similarly your taxes will depend on lots of factors some of which are unknown at this time (for example, which municipality you will your find a house at). What you could do is to search for salaries offered in the area (not necessarily for your profile) and see if the offer is in line with those. A first guide of thumb would be how many times the minimal income your salary will be.

Comment: @RonJohn I would say that it is off-topic, OP wants us to tell him if he should ask for more money and to do all of the research for him, and to tell him what his employer is willing to offer. If I had the privilege I would vote to close it.

Comment: Possibly on-topic at [expatriates.se] but usually you're told to check one of the cost-of-living comparison sites like [this one](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Gothenburg).

Comment: Maybe on topic at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ , but I'm doubting it is a good question either for any of the stackexchange sites because it is asking for a very subjective opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I lived and worked in Sweden for a few years.  What you need to do is create a sample budget on a monthly plan.

Your monthly income is approx 52k SEK.  Note that most salaries in Sweden are quoted AFTER tax (Nett) **(EDIT: This seems to be true for expats but not generally)** but you should confirm this for good order's sake.  I lived on 46k SEK per month, which with careful budgeting, was sufficient to support two people and have some fun.  I saved money by not taking alcohol (ridiculously expensive) and severely curtailing my eating out.

Next, write down your known monthly expenses.  You can find pricing for all of this online.  These will include:

- Rent (finding a place near/in Gothenburg should be easier than Stockholm, but I suggest you find one that is close to public transport.  Identify a few candidate places and use the median rent as your budget.  Also, if there is a waitlist, join it immediately.)
- Electricity (If you have electric heat, this could be a significant expense; in some cases it may be included in the rent)
- Internet / Telephone (The cheapest connection for you is probably Lycamobile; but you might like to have some data connection.  Municipalities often have an ethernet connection straight to each house, which you can use to get internet through Telia or a number of other providers.  I would suggest you start with your mobile phone data connections and then investigate cheaper alternatives over the next few months there.)
- Transportation (find an apartment near the metro and find the price of an all-access monthly pass - budget for two, one yours and one your wife's.  Later on when you have settled in you can figure out how to save money by bicycling and paying per ride with a kontantkort (cash card).)
- Insurance: you will want renter's insurance, life insurance, unemployment insurance, and if you purchase a car, car insurance.
- Union Dues: Unions in Sweden are a good thing.  I recommend joining the union for better deals on insurance, retirement, vacations, and job security.  Your company should be happy to facilitate this; if they're not I'd suggest looking elsewhere for work.
- Trip back home to India every year: This is a known expense so you can budget for it.

Add all that up, and with the remainder, allocate for your variable expenses:

- Groceries / food / eating out (as you don't know what your costs will be, put a generous guesstimate and fine-tune each month after you get there).  It's easy to spend about 6000 SEK per month on groceries if you are not careful.  It's also easy to reduce that to just around 2000 SEK per month.
- Saving: In general, plan to save to maintain an emergency fund of 3-6 month's of your expenses
- Investing: common rules of thumb say you should put about 15% monthly take-home into investments.  In Sweden, your employer will contribute to your retirement, but you can also contribute additionally.  Alternatively, you can invest in mutual funds or in family members back home in India.
- Saving for a car / house / bigger apartment / computer / any other goals you may have.

Your SEK 15,000 will not go very far as relocation expenses.  I suggest that it is best spent on good winter clothing (down-filled coats, ski mask hat, insulated gloves, pants, and boots for both you and your wife),  a two-burner stove / toaster oven, some pots and pans, and basic furniture.  Check out freecycle, the second hand stores like myrorna, humana, etc., and student housing trash rooms.

As a general guidance, avoid debt.  Do not take credit cards to purchase stuff new.  Buy stuff old and

Comment: "Do not take credit cards to purchase stuff".  Why not?  It's easy to pay CC by the due date, or even End Of Month and End Of Week (which is what I do).

Comment: @RonJohn, I do the same; use the CC and zero balance it every month.  However, when moving to a new country, it can be very easy to get flustered with the flurry of information, offers, and needs.  If OP wants a CC, they're free to do that, but better to wait until they have settled in, IMHO.  Also, the best way to build wealth is to avoid debt, mathematically.

Comment: Regarding the “salary after tax”, that I find strange, because every individual has their own “unique” tax-level based on the general levels (municipality, national etc) combined with individual deductions, eg for interest paid on loans, (work-) travel expenses etc. therefore it makes no sense to look at net levels, as two people may get paid the same gross, but take home vastly different amounts. Net Salary (or after tax salary) is typically something used for expats in Sweden, not for Swedish people more permanent residents.

Comment: @ssn, I was not aware that net salary was only for expats in Sweden, as my Swedish colleagues also talked in terms of net salary.  Thank you for clarifying!